# Should enumerations be placed in a separate file or within another class?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I currently have a class file with the following enumeration:

```
using System;

namespace Helper
{
    public enum ProcessType
    {
        Word = 0,
        Adobe = 1,
    }
}
```

Or should I include the enumeration in the class where it's being used?

I noticed Microsoft creates a new class file for DockStyle:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;

namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public enum DockStyle
    {
        None = 0, 
        Top = 1,
        Bottom = 2,
        Left = 3,
        Right = 4,.
        Fill = 5,
    }
}
```

Comment: The term "Enumerator" is confusing for me here, I automatically think of IEnumerator<T>. You mean Enumerable (= enum).

Comment: An `enum` isn't an "enumerator". It's an "enumerated type". An enumerator is something different.

Comment: You should replace enumerator by enumeration or enumerated type

Comment: It's neither "enumerable" nor "enumerator" nor "enumerated type" - it's "enumeration". (As per the spec, e.g. section 4.1.9.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Yeah that's what the spec says. I missed that part. All I could find in the spec when I checked was "enum". It's funny, though, because in his note on that section Eric Lippert referrs to it consistantly as an "enumerated type". I guess he followed the C terminology just like I did.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the enum is *only* relevant to one class, it may make sense to make it a nested type. If it could be used elsewhere, it makes sense to make it a top-level type.

Comment: I hesitated up-voting, because Jon Skeet has more reputation than God, but it's a good answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Critical Failure: If it's any consolation, it's way too late in the day for an upvote to make any rep difference.

Comment: On the other hand, Microsoft recommends to avoid public nested types, per FxCop rule (CA1034: NestedTypesShouldNotBeVisible): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx

Comment: He could still keep the enumeration type in the file but at the top level.  Keeping it in the file is still good if the only time it would ever change is when it's associated class would change and vice-versa.

Comment: @binarycoder: The reasons given aren't particularly compelling to me. FxCop would hate the builder that is generated for each Protocol Buffer class... ah well. I still think they're useful. Sometimes you *do* want logical grouping at a finer level than "namespace".

Answer (score 6):

Typically I see enumera**tions** placed in the class where they are being used if no other class will be using them, otherwise in their own file.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to create an Enum.cs file with all of my general use Enums, if I have enums that pretain to only ONE class then I have it nested.